# Appending a new dom element in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, element

I've created a custom component and I want to add child element when the component renders if a certain property is set to be `true`. I used the following code, but the component is not rendered. what am I doing wrong here.

```
    let deleteNode = '';
    if(deletable){
        deleteNode = '<div />'
    }

    let defaultClasses = 'chips chips-rounded';

    return (
        <div className={classNames(classes, defaultClasses)} onClick={ this.onClick }>
            {avatar}
            <span>{this.props.labelText}</span>
            {deleteNode}
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: you can use ternary `{deletable ? '<div />' : ''}`

Comment: Well your is much cleaner! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to render a component but actually you are just sending `string` in your `deleteNode`. Your code should be something like below

```
if(deletable){
    deleteNode = (<div />);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I different approach would be:

```
render() {
  const defaultClasses = 'chips chips-rounded'
  return (
    <div className={classNames(classes, defaultClasses)} onClick={ this.onClick }>
        {avatar}
        <span>{this.props.labelText}</span>
        {deletable && <div />}
    </div>
  )
}
```

So you don't need the extra `if` checking.